# Confused about weight and bias dependencies affecting learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I had a working LSTM model that had one weight/bias layer from its recurrent state to the output.  I then also coded up the same system, but with two layers. This means that I would have the LSTM, then a hidden layer, and then the output.  I wrote the lines to define this double layer model, but did not use them a single time.  But, now that those layers exist but are not used at all, it wouldn't learn! So my weights and biases are defined like so:

```
    weights = {                                                                                                                                                               
        # if going straight from PLSTM output to x,y prediction                                                                                                               
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([FLAGS.n_hidden, n_out], stddev=1/FLAGS.n_hidden, dtype=tf.float32)),                                                             

        # if fully connected feed-forward hidden layer between PLSTM output and x,y prediction                                                                                
        'outHidden1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([FLAGS.n_hidden, FLAGS.n_middle], dtype=tf.float32)),                                                                    
        'outHidden2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([FLAGS.n_middle, n_out], dtype=tf.float32))                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                                         

    biases = {                                                                                                                                                                
        # if going straight from PLSTM output to x,y prediction                                                                                                               
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_out], dtype=tf.float32)),                                                                                                      

        # if fully connected feed-forward hidden layer between PLSTM output and x,y predictio                                                                                 
        'outHidden1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([FLAGS.n_middle], dtype=tf.float32)),                                                                                    
        'outHidden2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_out], dtype=tf.float32))                                                                                              
    }
```

So I had the double layer weights and biases defined, but they were never used a single time in training or testing.

My incorporation of the weights/biases was a single line:

```
    return tf.matmul(relevant, weights['out']) + biases['out']
```

where relevant is the LSTM output.  So I am only using the 'out' variables in the weight and bias dictionaries.

It wouldn't learn anything.  Then, once I commented the double layer variables out like this:

```
    weights = {                                                                                                                                                               
        # if going straight from PLSTM output to x,y prediction                                                                                                               
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([FLAGS.n_hidden, n_out], stddev=1/FLAGS.n_hidden, dtype=tf.float32)),                                                             

        # if fully connected feed-forward hidden layer between PLSTM output and x,y prediction                                                                                
        # 'outHidden1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([FLAGS.n_hidden, FLAGS.n_middle], dtype=tf.float32)),                                                                    
        # 'outHidden2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([FLAGS.n_middle, n_out], dtype=tf.float32))                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                                         

    biases = {                                                                                                                                                                
        # if going straight from PLSTM output to x,y prediction                                                                                                               
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_out], dtype=tf.float32)),                                                                                                      

        # if fully connected feed-forward hidden layer between PLSTM output and x,y predictio                                                                                 
        # 'outHidden1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([FLAGS.n_middle], dtype=tf.float32)),                                                                                    
        # 'outHidden2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_out], dtype=tf.float32))                                                                                              
    }
```

...it started working again.  How does the existence of those variables impede learning? I initialize them, but no gradients should be running through them, and backprop shouldn't have any association with those unused variables. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Did you try running your program multiple times with those variables commented? Your system could be unstable for certain initializations

Comment: Yes, I ran it several times because I couldn't believe that that was the issue. It occurred consistently.

Comment: Have you tried to visualize the system on TensorBoard? Can you add the code used for optimizer / training as well? Also, no need to repeat the code which you commented.

Comment: Also, this might be stupid, but try to give a `name` to each of the variables you commented

Comment: I'm unfortunately not well acquainted with TensorBoard.  Giving them different names did the trick though.  Now the question is why... Perhaps some dependencies come up if they are all declared within the same dictionary?